# How to smooth my stamp date field in python

Tags: python, timestamp, time-series, lstm, arima

I have data (DateTime stamp) and corresponded value. The Date field which has a series of picked dates formatted as (dd/mm/yyyy hh:mm: ss) some rows have 3 values or more. Is there any way in python to take the average of the values at the same hour and save it in one row with the hour hh:00:00.

```
Example
01/01/2019 01:13       35 **
01/01/2019 01:38       37 **
01/01/2019 02:03       45 **
01/01/2019 02:15       46 **
01/01/2019 02:40       55 **
```

and need to be like :

```
01/01/2019 01:00       36 **
01/02/2019 02:00       50
```

Thanks

Comment: Does this answer your question? [averaging every five minutes data as one datapoint in pandas dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20048200/averaging-every-five-minutes-data-as-one-datapoint-in-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: Thanks, yes it looks useful with doing some modification. Thanks

Comment: if you want a rolling mean instead, you could also have a look at this: https://stackoverflow.com/q/49087038/10197418

Comment: This answered as following:-

df.set_index('Date').Count.resample('H').mean()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answered as following:-

df.set_index('Date').Count.resample('H').mean()